# how can write this query in django ORM

Tags: django-models

how to write in django ORM query select all rows(id) which id not userreg

select * from userreg where user_id not in (select user_id from emp_details)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
from django.db.models import Q
emp_id_list = Emp_details.objects.values('user_id')
res_list = Userreg.objects.filter(~Q(user_id__in = emp_id_list))
```